# Cannot find symbol NOTIFICATION_SERVICE?

Tags: java, android, notificationmanager

```
package com.test.app;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class runOnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver{

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

          NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   }
}
```

When I try to build the package, it says

```
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /home/mrburns/Desktop/myapp/bin/classes
    [javac] /home/mrburns/Desktop/myapp/src/com/test/app/runOnBoot.java:14: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
    [javac] location: class runOnBoot
    [javac]           NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    [javac]                                                                                           ^
    [javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 29):

I found calling this way works:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 10):

This should be `Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE`:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I see that is answer is currently being downvoted while it wasn't before. As it has been written in 2011, I suspect that some API updates make it deprecated though I didn't have time to check.

Answer (score 2):

For those using Kotlin,
the following line performs the same functionality as the other answers here.

```
val nm = context?.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
```

Comment: this solution has helped me. 
I needed to add the context.

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: In addition to your code please add some text to explain why your answer works or how it is different from previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

This should be

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should better try this

```
 NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: NOTIFICATION_SERVICE is a `public static final String`. You do not need any instance of `Context` to use it.

Comment: it can be accessed in both ways :) If  you are displaying the notification in Any web Service not in activity then you dont have the Context with you :)

Comment: You don't need any instance of Context. You statically call it from the class Context.